# C++ Displaying random set of six numbers

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to make a random number generator that displays six numbers at a time.

The first five numbers may range from **1-50**, the last number may range from **1-60**.

The way I currently have things set up, everything goes fine until the last number, which I've seen ranging into the 4000's while I am doing a test run. How can I fix this?

```
void Random::randGen()
{
    for (int counter = 1; counter <=6; ++counter)
    {
        if (counter == 6)
        {
            cout << (1 + rand() % 60);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << setw(5) << (1 + rand() % 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not putting a space before the last number. So you're seeing the last two numbers squashed together.

Comment: rand() isn't as random as you might think, it's much better to use std::mt19937 if your compiler supports it already

Comment: First, as mentioned, `rand` isn't a very good function. Second, even if it were, the modulo operation `%` is destroying the uniform probability distribution. In short, it makes smaller numbers more likely than larger numbers. http://tinyurl.com/qbj8vps

Answer (score 3):

Put the last number in a wide field, like the rest, so you get spacing between the last two columns.

```
        if (counter == 6)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << (1 + rand() % 60);
        }
```

Comment: Hahaha oh wow. I feel like an idiot now. Thank you very much for the easy solution. This is pretty funny.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for an if. Simply loop for 1..5 and place the last one after the loop

```
void Random::randGen()
{
   for (int counter = 1; counter <=5; ++counter)
   {
      cout << setw(5) << (1 + rand() % 50);
   }
   cout << setw(5) << (1 + rand() % 60);
}
```